# Error declaring TLS Version wrong in Charge plugin

Tags: plugin-charge

I am getting an error notice in the Squarebit Charge plugin saying This server doesn't support TLS 1.2. but when I check with the hosting provider (Arcustech, the best!) they assure me that the server does indeed support TLS 1.2

Further, I do not see any errors when I look at a charge detail in the connected Stripe account. This has just recently popped up on a few of my projects.

Make sense to anyone?

Comment: If you don't get a response from Michael (answer below), their Plugin changelog is here: https://transition.topshelfcraft.com/software/craft/charge/updates

Answer (score 2):

Stripe changed up some API URLs, which threw off Charge's legacy method for detecting TLS compatibility.

The erroneous warning is [fixed](https://twitter.com/TopShelfCraft/status/1051954976036028416) in [Charge 2.2.3](https://topshelfcraft.com/downloads/Charge-2-2-3.zip).

Comment: When can we expect a fix on this - pretty serious issue

Comment: Howdy @RoiAgneta — That erroneous warning is actually harmless, but definitely annoying. Update to Charge 2.2.3 to get rid of it. 

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is helpful to anyone reading this thread, but I hacked at this a bit and made the Charge_CompatibilityService class testTLS12minimum method echo the message from the exception. It indicated a failure resolving the API host. I commented out line 26 where it sets the $spiBase variable:

//\Stripe\Stripe::$apiBase = "https://api-tls12.stripe.com";

I assume it now falls back on the API host defined in the /vendor folder. This appears to have resolved the issue, though I haven't finished the rest of my Stripe account setup so I haven't confirmed it is working end to end.

Comment: The erroneous warning is [fixed](https://twitter.com/TopShelfCraft/status/1051954976036028416) in [Charge 2.2.3](https://topshelfcraft.com/downloads/Charge-2-2-3.zip).